# Get file list from server, optimization

Tags: php, linux

I want to do a list of files from linux server, length of the list will be from 0 to 100 per page. This is my function:

```
public function getReportList(){
    if (count(glob("/var/www/User/". $this->userId ."/*.pdf")) === 0 ) { 
        return 'empty';
    } 
    else {
        foreach (glob("/var/www/User/". $this->userId ."/*.pdf") as $filename) {
            $list .= "<tr>" . 
                        "<td>" . $this->getReportName(basename($filename)) . "</td>" .
                        "<td>" . basename($filename) . "</td>" .
                        "<td><a href='/download-reports-" . $this->userId . "-" . basename(substr($filename, 0, -4)) . "'>Pobierz</a></td>" .
                    "</tr>";
        }
        return $list;
    }  
}
```

I'm downloading the file names directly from the file list. On the basis of the file name I create date and other details of the file.

Recently I had the idea to list the files were saved in json or xml. I care about the speed of page loading. It seems to me that the list of files with json or xml will be a faster solution. I want to avoid using mysql.

Comment: It is likely that your bottleneck will be in the glob function call (benchmark to be sure!). If that's the case, the only real thing that will help is to cache the results of the glob call (it it is acceptable that results are not always realtime).

Comment: "I care about the speed of page loading" --- so this function **is** slow? How slow is it?

Comment: _I want to avoid using mysql_. I don't see how you could use it even if you were willing to.

Comment: Anyway, what is your question? Are you having trouble putting the information in JSON or XML? Show the code that does this, and we'll help you with it.